# Regular expression and URL Rewriting

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL **http://abc.com/v2/**  and now i want that if anyone put the URL something like this **http://abc.com/v2/abc** or **http://abc.com/v2/xyz** should be redirected to **http://abc.com/**

in general i want that anything put after /v2/  must be redirected to **http://abc.com/**

Please also tell me how to learn more about URL rewriting (for Apache environment) and  Regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the good RewriteRule you may apply:

```
RewriteRule  ^v2/(.*)  /$1   [QSA,R=301]
```

As for your other question, I do agree with Eric Johnson but here are my 2c:

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

### Two hints to help you doing the job faster:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

You use this tool when you want to check the URL and see if they're valid or not.

Comment: My pleasure. Thank *you* for being polite ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also that's a pretty basic rule then:

```
 RewriteRule  ^v2/  http://abc.com/   [R]
```

The `[R]` flag is for redirection, but in this case implied anyway. And the `^` start of subject marker would simply replace the leading `/` in your example.

As resources: http://regular-expressions.info/ for a regex tutorial, and [ServerFault: Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) for the RewriteRules, as well as the current manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

The first link in Google for "apache url rewriting":

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

I used mod_rewrite myself, it isn't hard. Please put forth a bit more effort before asking other people to Google things for you.

Comment: Not pleasant but perfectly adequate answer. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put on start page. Or create auto include file with this code:

```
$value = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pattern = "http://abc.com/v2/";
$rez = str_replace($pattern,"",$value);

if(strlen($rez)>0){
    echo "Here";
    header("Location: http://abc.com");
}
```

Comment: The redirect should be done in Apache using mod_rewrite, before ever reaching a handler.